# How to access recently used files by choosing from a list?

Tags: command-history, load, persistent-state

I would like to have a keystroke to show a **list of recently used files** to choose one to edit.

- What do I need to provide that?

And related,

- How do I manage the history of recently used files to use?
- This should support excluding filenames or subdirectories.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit on what you mean by "support excluding..."? Do you mean that you'd like to show a list of all files except some matching a pattern, or that you'd like to exclude certain files from *ever* showing up in the list? (The latter option is what @muru's answer with `autocmd` does; the former seems like it would be more useful and possibly easier to achieve.)

Comment: @KyleStrand I was thinking of the first variant, excluding a file if the path matches one of a list of patterns. For example, the patterns could be something like `*.tmp,/tmp/*,/mnt/foo/*`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`:browse`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Abrowse) command for that:

```
:browse oldfiles
```

For a keystroke, map it:

```
nnoremap <Leader>o :browse oldfiles<cr>
```

Then you can press <kbd>Leader o</kbd> in normal mode to view a list of files.

From [`:help v:oldfiles`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%3Aoldfiles):

```
                                        v:oldfiles oldfiles-variable
v:oldfiles      List of file names that is loaded from the viminfo file on
                startup.  These are the files that Vim remembers marks for.
                The length of the List is limited by the ' argument of the
                'viminfo' option (default is 100).
                When the viminfo file is not used the List is empty.
```

So, to limit at, say, 50 files, you can set [`viminfo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27viminfo%27):

```
set viminfo+='50
```

I don't see an easy way of excluding files from this, other than disabling `viminfo` using `autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufNew *.sh set viminfo=
```

This has the *huge* flaw of disabling all history for any session that involves  matching files.

Comment: That's an awesome feature that I'd never heard of.

Comment: Might it be possible to combine the `browse` command with [`unite`](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) and/or [`PipeCmd`](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/c8264794527c6be685829f08f63fd8dfa2903528/.vim/plugin/joeycommands.vim#L112-131) to achieve the filtering that OP would like?

Comment: @KyleStrand I have never used either, so I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Ctrl-P](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)'s MRU feature. Once you've installed it, type `:CtrlPMRUFiles` and it'll pop open a fuzzy finder at the bottom of the screen that you can fuzzy search through.[image]